# how to get json object in servlet from html which contain javascript?

Tags: java

can anyone plz give me solution for following problem ? this is my html code which have javascript function which 
 send data to servlet through json object and i want to know how to get that json object in servlet plz help....

```
index.html
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-    1">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">        </script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
<title>LoginInfo</title>
</head>

function loginResult(){
debugger;
var username=logForm.username.value;
var password=logForm.password.value;


var json={ uname:username,pwd:password} 

$.ajax({ 
url:'loginServlet', 
type:'post', 
dataType: 'json',
data:JSON.stringify(json),
success: function(data2) {
debugger;
$('‪#‎username‬').val(data.username); 
$('‪#‎password‬').val(data.password); 
} 
}); 

}
</script>

<body>
<form id="logForm" >
Login Id: <input type = "text" name = "name"/>
<br>
Password: <input type = "password" name = "password"/>
<br>
<input type = "button" value = "Login"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>

loginServlet.java
package net.codejava.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/loginServlet")
public class loginServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


//checking whether javascript jump into servlet or not
system.out.println("i am in servlet");

// read form fields
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");

System.out.println("username: " + username);
System.out.println("password: " + password);

// do some processing here...

// get response writer
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

// build HTML code
String htmlRespone = "<html>";
htmlRespone += "<h2>Your username is: " + username + "<br/>"; 
htmlRespone += "Your password is: " + password + "</h2>"; 
htmlRespone += "</html>";

// return response
writer.println(htmlRespone);

}

}
```

in this code how can i get json object in servlet .?
how to print json data in servlet ?
plz help..

Answer (score 0):

To get json in servlet

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (request.getInputStream()));
String str = br.readLine();
JSONObject req = new JSONObject(str);
```